# How to access to a specific character inside an element of a python list

Tags: python-3.x, list, numbers, point

I need to eliminate the point from a list of numbers, because then I need to convert numbers from string to integer.
The problem is that all the tools that I know to eliminate, as pop or remove are not possible with a string, how could I do?

L = ['1.', '2.', '3.', '4.']

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try convert to `float` first then to `int`, or if you are confident that all your input strings end with `.`, then you can simply remove it by `str.replace` or using a slice.

```py
>>> L = ['1.', '2.', '3.', '4.']
>>> [int(float(item)) for item in L]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [int(item.replace('.', '')) for item in L]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [int(item[:-1]) for item in L]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way is:

```
L = [item.strip(".") for item in L]
```

you can also convert to integer in the same loop:

```
L = [int(item.strip(".")) for item in L]
```